# I'm really new to php and I have to write a simple contact form for my school assignment. But the data I input won't show on the result

Tags: php, html, forms

This is the html form i wrote.

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post ">
        <p> Naam Quizploeg: <input type="text" name="Naam Quizploeg" value="" placeholder="Naam Quizploeg"><br> </p>
        <p> Emailadres: <input type="text" name="Emailadres" value=""placeholder="Emailadres"><br> </p>
        <p>Naam Kapitein: <input type="text" name="Naam Kapitein"placeholder="Naam Kapitein"> </p>
        <input type="submit"name="verzenden" value="Verzenden">
```

And i used this php method to get my input from the form

```
Hallo <?php echo $_POST["NaamKapitein"]; ?> <br>
        Uw emailadres is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?> <br>
        U bent hierbij ingeschreven voor de bilbiotheekquiz onder
        de naam <?php echo $_POST["NaamQuizploeg"]; ?>.
```

If anyone can help me out or point out my mistakes i would be delighted

Comment: @KUMAR: please do not embolden whole sentences - that does not make text more readable, and it is not a good use of Review Queue time.

Comment: Try including `var_dump($_POST);` in your welcome.php and see if you have any clues from there.

Comment: Might be the space in `method="post "`

Comment: Also, `$_POST["NaamKapitein"]` does not exist, you have `name="Naam Kapitein""`. same for `$_POST["email"]`: `name="Emailadres"` and `$_POST["NaamQuizploeg"]`: `name="Naam Quizploeg"`

Comment: Alright I changed the spaces and the incorrect names that was kinda dumb of me that I didn't notice that. Unfortunately that didn't do it either.

Comment: @Hendrik Dockx so it means your problem is solved or not??

Answer (score 0):

The name of the placeholder are with spaces and the names of the echo's are without spaces. Maybe change that?

Comment: Placeholders are just that, placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML PAGE:-**

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
    <p> Naam Quizploeg: <input type="text" name="NaamQuizploeg" value="" placeholder="Naam Quizploeg"><br> </p>
    <p> Emailadres: <input type="text" name="email" value=""placeholder="Emailadres"><br> </p>
    <p>Naam Kapitein: <input type="text" name="NaamKapitein"placeholder="Naam Kapitein"> </p>
    <input type="submit" name="verzenden" value="Verzenden">
```

**welcome.php**

```
Hallo <?php echo $_POST["NaamKapitein"]; ?> <br>
Uw emailadres is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?> <br>
U bent hierbij ingeschreven voor de bilbiotheekquiz onder
de naam <?php echo $_POST["NaamQuizploeg"]; ?>
```

**Note:-** the `name` of form input should be same as `$_POST['name'];`

Comment: Yeah i noticed it and changed it. (the 'Emailadres' one right?) Unfortunately it still won't show the data i input into the form.

Comment: space in `method="post "`

Comment: also do space between  `<input type="submit" name="verzenden">` attributes name.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you,the main idea of this code is that first you should check if the form has been submitted via the submit button, the isset() function does that and then only if submit button is clicked the values should be printed.Please comment below if you do not understand , ill be glad to help you out.And also:
1.Pay attention to the name attribute of the input tag(), it should match with your php post variable <$_POST["**name_here**"].
2.Try to beautify your code.
3.Welcome to coding.Enjoy!

your html form page(.html)

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
        <p> Naam Quizploeg:</p>
        <input type="text" name="NaamQuizploeg" value="" placeholder="Naam Quizploeg"><br>
        <p> Emailadres:</p>
        <input type="text" name="Emailadres" value="" placeholder="Emailadres"><br>
        <p>Naam Kapitein:</p>
        <input type="text" name="NaamKapitein" placeholder="Naam Kapitein"> <br>
        <input type="submit" name="verzenden" value="Verzenden">
</form>
```

Your php page (welcome.php)

```
 <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['verzenden'])){ 
            echo "Hallo".$_POST["NaamKapitein"]."<br>";
            echo "Uw emailadres is: ".$_POST["Emailadres"]."<br>";
            echo "U bent hierbij ingeschreven voor de bilbiotheekquiz onder de naam: ".$_POST["NaamQuizploeg"];
        }
   ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm fairly new to all these thinks so it's still very confusing. I ran the code as above but now it gives the following output:



"; echo "Uw emailadres is: ".$_POST["Emailadres"]."
"; echo "U bent hierbij ingeschreven voor de bilbiotheekquiz onder de naam: ".$_POST["NaamQuizploeg"]; } ?>

Comment: @HendrikDockx Do you have a webserver running that supports PHP?

Comment: I will check that. Maybe that is the problem!

Comment: You can install wamp server on your pc.https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/

Answer (score 0):

Please check your name atributes in the html form and then use the same name in the php file to get the data from the form. For example if the name atribute is: name="exampleee", you have to use $_POST['exampleee'];